# concurrentStoreAndDispatch - where and how can I set it's value

Tags: amazon-mq

I am dealing with a migration to AWS AmazonMQ.
I would like to set this value,"concurrentStoreAndDispatch", and cant find a way to change the default value.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the configuration of the broker - it is in the XML as a comment.

`concurrentStoreAndDispatch` and set it as you need.